# Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format. Parse not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error "Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format." It seems my Convert and Parse is not working. Im using ASP.NET C#. Also is there a way to just read numeral values instead of using textbox?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="Payroll" runat="server">
<div>

    <h1>Exception Painting</h1>
    <h2>Payroll Calculator</h2>

    <p>Employee Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <p>Pay Rate: <asp:TextBox ID="PayRate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <p>Salary Employee: <asp:TextBox ID="SalaryEmployee" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <p>Hours Worked: <asp:TextBox ID="HoursWorked" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

     <asp:Button ID="Submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />

</div>
</form>

<%
    double overtimeHours = 0;
    double overtimePay = 0;
    double regularPay = 0;
    double totalPay = 0;
    double regularHours = 0;
    double basePay = 0;
    double hrsWrked = 0;
    double payRt = 0;

    string nm = Name.Text;

    hrsWrked = Convert.ToDouble(HoursWorked.Text);
    //I cant figure out what im doing wrong here..
    hrsWrked = double.Parse(HoursWorked.Text);

    string slry = Name.Text;

    payRt = Convert.ToDouble(PayRate.Text);
    payRt = double.Parse(PayRate.Text);

    double overtimePayRt = payRt * 1.5;

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Payroll.Visible = false;

        if (SalaryEmployee.Equals("no") && hrsWrked > 40)
            overtimeHours = hrsWrked - 40;
            regularHours = hrsWrked - overtimeHours;
            overtimePay = overtimeHours * overtimePayRt;
            regularPay = payRt * regularHours;
            totalPay = overtimePay + regularPay;
            basePay = hrsWrked * 52 * totalPay;
            Response.Write("Employee Name: " + nm + "Base Salary: " + basePay + "Hours Worked: " + hrsWrked + "Total Weekly Pay: " + totalPay);

        if (SalaryEmployee.Equals("yes"))
            regularHours = 40;
            totalPay = payRt * regularHours;
            basePay = hrsWrked * 52 * totalPay;
            Response.Write("Employee Name: " + nm + "Base Salary: " + basePay + "Hours Worked: "           + hrsWrked + "Total Weekly Pay: " + totalPay);
    }
    %>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code is running as soon as I hit debug! so the text field is blank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are parsing and converting uninitialized values

```
<p>Employee Name: <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<p>Pay Rate: <asp:TextBox ID="PayRate" runat="server">0.0</asp:TextBox>
<p>Salary Employee: <asp:TextBox ID="SalaryEmployee" runat="server">0.0</asp:TextBox>
<p>Hours Worked: <asp:TextBox ID="HoursWorked" runat="server">0.0</asp:TextBox>
```

this will get your code to compile but you will need to be checking these values every time the user changes them cause it will break as soon as you have values that won't parse or convert correctly

here is an example of one way to catch errors for this.

```
bool bueno = true;//spanish for good




try
{
    payRt = Convert.ToDouble(PayRate.Text);
    payRt = double.Parse(PayRate.Text);
    //I cant figure out what im doing wrong here..
    hrsWrked = double.Parse(HoursWorked.Text);
}
catch (System.FormatException fEX)
{
    bueno = false;
    Response.Write(fEX.Message);//you could do more here 
}
catch (System.OverflowException ofEX)
{
    bueno = false;
    Response.Write(ofEX.Message);//you could do more here 
}
catch (System.ArgumentException aEX)
{
    bueno = false;
    Response.Write(aEX.Message);//you could do more here 
}

//I would do more about these errors but this is an example


if(bueno)
{
    double overtimePayRt = payRt * 1.5;

    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
```

Comment: How would i initialize them? Sorry im really new to this lol. Also thanks for the reply!

Comment: @user3505204 notice in the first lines of code I posted the right before `</asp:TextBox>` I put the `0.0`  remember you can't use 0 cuase that didn't fix it when I was looking at this. but with the Exception catching you don't have to initialize but that means that you are cause errors on purpose

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much its up and running! I didnt know it was that easy to initialize, i was looking everywhere.